# Getting error __dopostback is undefined in IE 10 browser for link button

Tags: javascript, asp.net

In ASP.net 3.5 app, I am using link button which calls sever event. 
the link button works fine up to *IE 9* or *FF* but in *IE 10* it throws error.

```
"__dopostback is undefined"
```

Answer (score 0):

I got some solution:
I forgot to mention i was using ScriptManager too so, i disabled the  EnablePartialRendering="false"

and

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/da-DK/iewebdevelopment/thread/16fa6eb9-255c-4d92-a183-06d8ed2fc8f6

Answer (score 0):

Download Hotfix this is microsoft patch it will resolve the issue as per my experience.

```
.NET 4 - [http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2600088][1]
.NET 2.0
   [2][2] for Win7 SP1/Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1, Windows Vista/Server 2008, Windows XP/Server 2003
    [3][3] for Win7/Windows Server 2008 R2 RTM
```